# Get Zero before an integer from database

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
If dr.Read Then
     mtCompareWeek.Text = dr("Week").ToString()
End If
```

The value from my access database is `03`.. But it only appears as 3. What should I do to get "03" in the textbox?
*`CStr` did not work either.

Comment: Did you try `dr.GetString("Week")`

Comment: No, the value from your database is 3. Pure numbers **do not have padding information**. A 3 is a 3 is a 3. There is precisely no difference between 3, 03, and 003 - they are *the same thing*. How you choose to *display* that 3 is another matter (as is: how any arbitrary developer-aimed database query tool chooses to display it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the String overload to specify the number of digits:

```
If dr.Read Then
     mtCompareWeek.Text = dr("Week").ToString("00")
End If
```

Or you could use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
If dr.Read Then
     mtCompareWeek.Text = String.Format("{0:00}", dr("Week"))
End If
```

Comment: Second option is the answer, will accept this later. ty

Answer (score 4):

You should use a [format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)

```
mtCompareWeek.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}", dr("Week"))
```

Answer (score 1):

[How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
int indexOfColumn = dr.GetOrdinal("Week");
mtCompareWeek.Text = dr.GetInt32(indexOfColumn).ToString("D2")
```

or with [`String.PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
mtCompareWeek.Text = dr.GetInt32(indexOfColumn).ToString().PadLeft(2, "0"c)
```

Comment: the other answers worked for me. Yours gives me a conversion error. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: @AdorableVB: whoops, `GetInt32` expects the index of the column not the name, corrected.